# Where does this quote in Romans 2:24 come from?

Tags: romans, paul

KJV Romans 2 : 24

> For the name of God is blasphemed among the Gentiles through you, as it is written.

Where does this quote come from?

Comment: check footnotes of bible versions and the TSK chain reference available on biblehub.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quote comes from Isaiah 52:5 which reads in the NKJV as

> Now therefore, what have I here,” says the LORD, “That My people are
> taken away for nothing? Those who rule over them Make them wail,” says
> the LORD, “And My name is blasphemed continually every day.

If you are looking for a closer quote, Paul is actually quoting from the LXX which reads

> And now why are ye here? Thus saith the Lord, Because my people was
> taken for nothing, wonder ye and howl. Thus saith the Lord, On account
> of you my name is continually blasphemed among the Gentiles.